# Implode/explode a string: what escaping scheme would you suggest?

Tags: java, string, escaping, delimiter

Suppose I have two strings to "join" with a delimiter.

```
String s1 = "aaa", s2 = "bbb"; // input strings
String s3 = s1 + "-" + s2; // join the strings with dash
```

I can use `s3.split("-")` to get `s1` and `s2`. Now, what if `s1` or `s2` contains dashes? Suppose also that `s1` and `s2` may contain any ASCII printable and I don't want to use non-printable characters as a delimiter.

What kind of *escaping* would you suggest in this case?

Comment: You delimiter really needs to be unique or easy to discerne based on context. If you chose the dash as delimiter, you need to decide on some rules that indicate when a dash is a delimiter and when it's just a dash. You could use an escape code of some sort or say when a dash is between quotes it is not a delimiter. The OpenCSV solution offered by @user714965 seems like a good idea if you can use it. Or change you delimiter to something else like || or something else that is unlikely to appear in your strings.

Answer (score 4):

If I could define the format, delimiters, etc. I would use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and use it's defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an uncommon character sequence, such as `;:;` as a delimiter instead of a single character.

Comment: What if this sequence does appear in a "joined" string ?

Comment: That would need escaping. Suppose you're using the dash as a delimiter. To display the dash character in the final string without breaking the split, you would type something like `\-`. To display `\-` in the final string you would type `\\-` etc. by escaping the escape character. This isn't without its pitfalls, though. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Solutions

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working solution, that doesn't use a separator, but that joins the lengths of the strings at the end of the imploded string to be able to re-explode it after:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String imploded = implode("me", "and", "mrs.", "jones");
    System.out.println(imploded);
    String[] exploded = explode(imploded);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(exploded));
}

public static String implode(String... strings) {
    StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder lengths = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String string : strings) {
        concat.append(string);
        if (i > 0) {
            lengths.append("|");
        }
        lengths.append(string.length());
        i++;
    }
    return concat.toString() + "#" + lengths.toString();
}

public static String[] explode(String string) {
    int last = string.lastIndexOf("#");
    String toExplode = string.substring(0, last);
    String[] lengths = string.substring(last + 1).split("\\|");
    String[] strings = new String[lengths.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (String length : lengths) {
        int l = Integer.valueOf(length);
        strings[i] = toExplode.substring(0, l);
        toExplode = toExplode.substring(l);
        i++;
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Prints:

```
meandmrs.jones#2|3|4|5
[me, and, mrs., jones]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store those strings in an array and join them with dash each time you want to display them to user?

Comment: Let's say it is out of scope :)